# Perceptron doesn't find the right line even with a bias (Processing)

Tags: java, neural-network, processing, perceptron

My perceptron doesn't find the right y-intercept even though I added a bias. The slope is correct. This is my second try coding a perceptron from scratch and I got the same error twice.
The perceptron evaluates if a point on a canvas is higher or lower than the interception line. The inputs are the x-coordinate, y-coordinate and 1 for the bias.

> Perceptron class:

```
class Perceptron
{
  float[] weights;

  Perceptron(int layerSize)
  {
    weights = new float[layerSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < layerSize; i++)
    {
      weights[i] = random(-1.0,1.0);
    }
  }

  float Evaluate(float[] input)
  {
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++)
    {
      sum += weights[i] * input[i];
    }
    return sum;
  }

  float Learn(float[] input, int expected)
  {
    float guess = Evaluate(input);
    float error = expected - guess;

    for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++)
    {
      weights[i] += error * input[i] * 0.01;
    }

    return guess;
  }
}
```

> This is the testing code:

```
PVector[] points;

float m = 1; // y = mx+q  (in canvas space)
float q = 0; //

Perceptron brain;

void setup()
{
  size(600,600);

  points = new PVector[100];
  for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
  {
    points[i] = new PVector(random(0,width),random(0,height));
  }

  brain = new Perceptron(3);
}

void draw()
{
  background(255);
  DrawGraph();
  DrawPoints();
  //noLoop();
}

void DrawPoints()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
  {
    float[] input = new float[] {points[i].x / width, points[i].y / height, 1};

    int expected = ((m * points[i].x + q) < points[i].y) ? 1 : 0; // is point above line

    float output = brain.Learn(input, expected);

    fill(sign(output) * 255);

    stroke(expected*255,100,100);
    strokeWeight(3);
    ellipse(points[i].x, points[i].y, 20, 20);
  }
}

int sign(float x)
{
  return x >= 0 ? 1 : 0;
}

void DrawGraph()
{
  float y1 = 0 * m + q;
  float y2 = width * m + q;

  stroke(255,100,100);
  strokeWeight(3);

  line(0,y1,width,y2);
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to do some [debugging](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) to figure out exactly where your code behaves differently from what you expected. Try to [break your problem down into smaller steps](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and post a [mcve] of just one step. Good luck.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Thanks for the reply. I tested around a little bit and found out the problem was I had to „sign“ the result before calculating the error.

Comment: You're welcome. Do you want to post the answer, or would you rather I expand my comment into an answer?

Comment: I can post an answer

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem

```
float guess = Evaluate(input);
float error = expected - guess;
```

should be

```
float guess = sign(Evaluate(input));
float error = expected - guess;
```

The output was never exactly one ore zero even if the answer would be correct. Because of this even the correct points gave a small error that stopped the perceptron from finding the right answer. By calculating the sign of the answer first the error is 0 if the answer is correct.

Comment: It might benefit you to explain *why* this solution worked for you, so that someone else reading this can understand what you did